# Nothing to boot: No such file or directory

Tags: development-environment

Hi guys i was trying to set up ubuntu server in VirtualBox until this happened was written Nothing to boot :no such file or directory i don't how to solve this can someone help

I did literally everything to solve it but it didn't work

Comment: Take a look again at [ask]. Folks who might be able to help you currently have no way of knowing what's included in "literally everything" or why those things didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Do you changed the path of the Ubuntu Boot file or removed the file?

It seems like there is no such file in the directory you selected at begin of setup.

Try to move the file back there or download the file again.